# Linux Remote Desktop over the internet, Remmina or other free clients?

Tags: ssh, networking, vnc, remote-desktop, remmina

I'm trying unsuccessfully to remote desktop from a linux mint 18.3 to another linux mint computer over the internet, without messing with the routers settings or manually opening ports, something similar to TeamViewer for Windows. I've read many links but all involve some manual changes in the remote routers, which I'm not able to do.

I've installed remmina, a vnc server, enabled Desktop Sharing to both computers, but I find it impossible to connect. Also I'm trying it with any protocol, VNC, SSH, NX. So my question is, is there any free software that will take care of the port settings seamlessly, to simply enter the remote local IP and establish a connection? Note, this connection is over the internet.

Thank you.

Comment: Teamviewer is not opensource but is free for personal use - https://www.teamviewer.us/latest-version/. The other one that I've never gotten around to trying but looked about the best in terms of it being a web browser served client is Guacamole - https://guacamole.apache.org/.

Comment: Overview of the install looks pretty easy - https://www.ostechnix.com/apache-guacamole-access-computer-anywhere-via-web-browser/ or this one - https://mangolassi.it/topic/10295/installing-guacamole-on-centos-7.

Comment: Did you try TeamViewer for Linux? It worked rather well whenever I use it.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. I was trying not to use TeamViewer because it's not open source, however I ended up using it because I didn't have any other simple option. 
And TeamViewer worked very well, it supported file transfer as well. So for now I'll be using it, but I'm gonna keep my eyes open for a simple open-source option in the future.

Comment: any updates on this @lind?